# How do i create public folder on non-removable external device

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to android.

According to the android documentation getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() can be used to access the public directory of external storage.

Without a memory card on the device that am testing on, I am not able to create public folders (i.e. they should remain even after my app is uninstalled).

After some research on the internet, and if I am not misunderstanding, I came to understand that external storage does not necessarily mean a memory card but public directories which can be shared between phones and viewed when phone is connected to a laptop.

So why is the above method not able to access the public directory for folder creation when memory card is unmounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External storage does not necessarily mean memory card, it's true, it can also refer to internal storage.

Also, to store a file as public in **Internal Storage**, you can use the below code:

```
String rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File rootDirectory = new File(rootDir + "/Education/your_file_name.pdf");
```

**Note:** Even if it says `getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();` it will fetch you the address to Internal Storage by default, and not the SD card.

To access SD card storage, you must implement something called as the **Document Tree**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tanks i appreciate.The fault was partly mine. You see i would go to my settings and unmount the sd card before testing, i guess this also affects the nonremovable external storage. Your code worked after i had the device restart.

Comment: @Benny Glad I could help :))